# Repeat rows dynamically in Oracle based on a condition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, connect-by

Heres what i have

**Query**

```
with temp as (
select 11 as x  from dual
union
select 222 as x  from dual
)
select x from temp t,(SELECT 1
          FROM DUAL 
         CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 3)
```

**Output**

```
X
--
11
222
11
222
11
222
```

**Output i desire**

```
X
--
11
11
222    
222
222
```

basically i would like the row to repeat itself based on the length of the column 'X' value.
so if value is 'abc'
then that  row should repeat 3 times

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works:

```
with temp as (
select '11' as x  from dual
union
select '222' as x  from dual
)
SELECT x, LEVEL from temp t
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(t.x) 
and prior x = x
and prior sys_guid() is not null;
```

Last line does the trick. Same can be achieved with other reference to PRIOR:

```
with temp as (
select '11' as x  from dual
union
select '222' as x  from dual
)
SELECT x, LEVEL from temp t
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(t.x) 
and PRIOR x = x
and PRIOR DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE () IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Any non-deterministic function works (as I didn't quite say in my answer...)

Comment: If you've got a link to somewhere that explains why that works, it might be useful to add that. I saw it used somewhere ages but don't know where, and I don't think that explained it anyway.

Comment: There is a question here: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2526535?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 2):

Since you're on 11g you can use [recursive subquery factoring](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#sthref6730) to achieve this:

```
with t as (
  select 11 as x  from dual
  union all
  select 222 as x  from dual
),
r (x, idx, len) as (
  select x, 1, length(x)
  from t
  union all
  select r.x, r.idx + 1, r.len
  from r
  where r.idx < r.len
)
select x from r
order by x;

    X
-----
   11
   11
  222    
  222
  222
```

The anchor member gets the original rows and the length of the value.The recursive member adds one to `idx` until it reaches the length.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/35241).

You can do it with a hierarchical query too:

```
with t as (
  select 11 as x  from dual
  union all
  select 222 as x  from dual
)
select x
from t
connect by level <= length(x)
and prior x = x
and prior sys_guid() is not null;
```

The combination of the two `prior` clauses - one restricitng duplicates, the other involing a non-deterministic function to prevent cycling when you do that - gives you the desired rows:

```
    X
-----
   11
   11
  222    
  222
  222
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/35255).

Answer (score -1):

```
with temp as (
    select 11 as x  from dual
    union
    select 222 as x  from dual
)
select x from temp t,(
    SELECT 1
    FROM DUAL 
    CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 3)
order by 1
```

Comment: please expand and explain what this code does instead of just dumping lines of code as an 'answer'